# ROS2 colcon ament: includes non-existent path /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/include . How to set the folder to python3/?

Tags: ros2, python, colcon, include, compilation

I build an ament package A on a docker container on the cloud.

Then, I build locally package B that has A (which I pulled via conan) as dependency. And I see this error

```
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Imported target "A::A__rosidl_generator_py"
  includes non-existent path

    "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/include"

  in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.  Possible reasons include:

  * The path was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and references files it does not
  provide.
```

In my local PC I have numpy installed, but on a different path

`/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy` instead of

`/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy`

On the docker image there is only `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/`, how do I allow searching for numpy or any other python package also in `/usr/local/lib/python3/` ?

Or is there some problem with my local python installation?

Answer (score 0):

Set the include directory to point to the correct numpy path. You can do this by adding a line in the CMakeLists.txt like:

```
include_directories(/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include)
```

OR

create a symlink from the expected numpy include path to the actual one.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy
```

Comment: That is a package from ros2 and to my understanding it already does

include_directories(/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/include)

instead of something like

include_directories($PYTHON_LIB_DIR/dist-packages/numpy/core/include)

or maybe it does that, but it's resolved when the package is built on the cloud and then when I use it locally the paths do not agree.

I create the symlink, but it's not a clean solution. E.g. if there is going to be a new dependency, I will have to create a new link. I would like for things to just work

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Marcus will resolve your exact compilation issue. However I think that this is more of an [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). In particular you need to be taking a step back and understanding what you're doing when you're building on one platform and running on a different one with different versions of dependencies.

This fix will likely get the include file to work. But you need to make sure that any binary dependencies are ABI compatible. If they are not you will get unexplained memory corruption and or crashes.

So to that end you will want to audit all your dependencies on the different systems and make sure that the two systems are close enough before trying to transfer binaries between them. An example where this wouldn't be expected to work is compiling a binary on Ubuntu 20.04 and then expecting it to work on 22.04 unless it's statically compiled to eliminate most dependencies except the core runtime environment. But if you're close enough you may be luck and it will work some of the time. It's just not guaranteed. The fewer dependencies and the more similar the platforms the more likely it is to work.

Comment: Yes, I think this is what happens probably. However, the image we use to build is Ubuntu 22, and I have Ubuntu 22, but somehow the python dist-packages installation paths differ.

My hope was that colcon could allow more paths for python packages. Or at least I do not understand why I have a python3 and a python3.10 when they are actually the same.

If they are not, how could I get only the 3.10 folder? I tried installing python and reinstalling, and it didn't solve the problem ;(

Comment: You likey installed python from different methods or different sources on the different systems. The best way to resolve this is to make sure you're using the debian packages and have the same versions from the same sources.